# How to speed up the initialization of a .NET client application (Windows Forms or WPF)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, winapi

Sometimes I create some quick personal projects using [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) with [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) or [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). I have noticed that managed applications can take 2x or 3x times longer to start compared with native applications.

I have written a "Quick Notes" application, however it isn't very "quick". :-(

What are some techniques to speed up the initialization of Windows Forms/WPF applications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163808.aspx)

Also, if you are loading lots of data on load, move it to another thread and show an indicator or something (while it's loading) so at least the form pops up quickly, even if it takes a little longer for the actual data to load.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 3.5 SP1 does tend to make start up a little quicker. Also see a [series of blog posts](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/09/displaying_a_splash_screen_with_c_introduction.html) on putting up a splash screen (in native C++) while starting the WPF application at the Logos Blog.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 3.5 SP1 also now includes the ability to create a fast SplashScreen without using C++

Comment: Do you have a link on this?  How do we use this?

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to consider moving processing off to worker threads. When your app starts load the root UI, but not the data - rather load the data async (and create pad windows etc. as each data item comes in).

Answer (score 0):

.NET applications made for .NET 3.0 or later work much better on newer versions of Windows, Windows Vista, Windows 7, etc. I think in a few years time the difference between managed and unmanaged code in terms of performance will unnoticeable.